# UIButton Border Color on Selected State using IBInspectable

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift-extensions, ibinspectable

I am using `@IBInspectable` to set a border color on a `UIButton` using a Swift extension like this:

```
extension UIButton {
  @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
      return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
      layer.borderWidth = newValue
      layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
  }
}
```

...but I also want to have a `selectedBorderColor` property for the `.Selected` state of the button. Is this possible with an extension like this? Do I have to subclass `UIButton` and check the button state somehow instead?

```
extension UIButton {
  @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
      return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
      layer.borderWidth = newValue
      layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
  }
  //This is what I want to do...
  @IBInspectable var selectedBorderWidth: CGFloat {
    get {
      return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
      layer.borderWidth = newValue
      layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can subclass `UIButton` like this:

```
class SBButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var borderColor : UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var selectedBorderColor : UIColor = UIColor.blackColor() {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if selected {
                layer.borderColor = selectedBorderColor.CGColor
            } else {
                layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use `button.selected = true`